# Change the element in a matrix based on the value of the corresponding element in another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

First of all I want to generate a random matrix which size is the same as the input matrix. If an element value  in random matrix is greater than 0.5 , then l have to increment the value of corresponding element in the input matrix by one, else decrement by 1.

```
X=[4       5        6  ;    7       8        9   ;     3        2       1]
Random=[ 0.65     0.43     0.23   ;       0.75     0.12      0.78  ;    0.31     0.96       0.58]
```

Comment: What are `X` and `Y`? Which one do you want to modify?

Comment: I want to modify X.   Y is the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing to create a matrix of `true` values where `Random` is greater than `0.5` and `false` otherwise.

```
Random = rand(size(X));
greater_than_one_half = Random > 0.5;
```

You can then use this logical matrix to select and manipulate certain elements of `X` or `Y`.

```
% Add one to all values in X where Random > 0.5
X(greater_than_one_half) = X(greater_than_one_half) + 1;

% Subtract one from all values in X where Random <= 0.5
X(~greater_than_one_half) = X(~greater_than_one_half) - 1;
```

Or you could do something clever and use the negation (`~`) of the logical array as an exponent for `-1` such that when it's `false` (0), it's `-1` (`-1^(~0)`) and when it's `true` (1), it's `1` (`-1^(~1)`). Then add this to `X`.

```
X = X + (-1).^(~greater_than_one_half);
```

Or simply:

```
X = X + (-1).^(Random <= 0.5);
```